# How to add custom icons to maplibre unclustered markers using filter

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl, markerclusterer, maplibre-gl

I am adding maker clusters using maplibre gl and when markers are unclustering, I want to add specific image to individual marker based on id present in properties of geojson of that feature.

https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/example/cluster/

This is simple clustering example, can anyone help?